# PyQT5 как для двух и более QTextBox -ов назначить фильтр событий?

Tags: python, pyqt5

подскажите пожалуйста как назначить один и тот же фильтр событий для нескольких QTextBox -ов. Хочется сделать переключение между несколькими текстовыми полями клавишей Tab, сам виджет перехватывает нажатие и получается табуляция. QWidget.setTabOrder c QTextBox почему то у меня не заработал, а вот с QLineEdit работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Нет в Qt QTextBox, есть QTextEdit и QTextPlaintText. Под фильтром событий вы имеете ввиду installEventFilter?

Comment: Извините ошибся, да QTextEdit, да имел ввиду installEventFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте у вашего [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) / [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html) вызвать [setTabChangesFocus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#tabChangesFocus-prop)

```
text.setTabChangesFocus(True)
```

---

Описание [setTabChangesFocus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#tabChangesFocus-prop):

> This property holds whether Tab changes focus or is accepted as input.
>
> In some occasions text edits should not allow the user to input
>   tabulators or change indentation using the Tab key, as this breaks the
>   focus chain. The default is false.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Заработало!!! Надаже всего то  1 строчка, а я с installEventFilter  мучился))

Comment: @Drop86 если данный ответ решил вашу проблему, то не забывайте отметить его как правильный.